# PyQGIS update field in line dataset when it is within a polygon

Tags: pyqgis-3

I am trying to update a field in a (Road centerline) table based on a value from another table when it is within a Polygon (Locality boundaries).

Based on posts like [QGIS layer.geometry.intersection() not finding intersections between layers](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/217737/qgis-layer-geometry-intersection-not-finding-intersections-between-layers) I have the following code. Both datasets are in EPSG:28355. It never prints ntext=b['Locality_N'] - so obviously something is wrong with the if within statement.

```
    import re

    def Update_Field(fieldName, ntext): # Function to simplify updating fields
        print (ntext)
        fieldIndex = layer.fields().indexFromName(fieldName)
        dpr.changeAttributeValues({f.id(): {fieldIndex: ntext}})
        layer.commitChanges()

    RoadType_dict = {'Rd':'Road', 'Avenue': 'Ave'}
    layer = iface.activeLayer()
    selection = layer.getFeatures() #all features
    #selection = layer.selectedFeatures() #only selected features

    #Locality Data
    Locality_layer=QgsVectorLayer(r'Z:\My Drive\Mangoesmapping\Spatial Projects\Gen_Library\DSC\vector\DSC_Localities_areas.shp', "Locality", "ogr")

    dpr = layer.dataProvider()

    for f in selection:
        print (f.id())
        text=f['RoadMntnc']
        print (text)
        stext=re.split('_+', text)

    ##Update Road Type
    #    ntext=RoadType_dict.get(stext[-1:][0])
    #    fieldName='Type'
    #    Update_Field(fieldName,ntext)

    ##Update LocalityName
        for b in Locality_layer.getFeatures():
            if f.geometry().within(b.geometry()):
                print (b.geometry())
                ntext=b['Locality_N']
                fieldName="Locality"
                Update_Field(fieldName,ntext)

    layer.commitChanges()
    layer.updateFields()
```

I have commented out the code that works but is not required for these tests.

--- Based on [another answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/331486/in-pyqgis-can-i-get-the-total-length-of-a-road-where-its-broken-up-into-segment/331512?noredirect=1#comment540997_331512) I also tried

```
e = QgsExpression( "geomwithin('Locality_layer','Locality_N') ")
f[fieldName] = e.evaluate()
layer.updateFeature(f)
```

But the values aren't updated in the table.

Comment: Hi George, I'm not sure if I'm reading your problem correctly, but I'm wondering if you need to nest your for loops - at the moment it looks as though your for b loop loops through everything in your Locality_layer but it only tests one geometry from 'f'?

Comment: @Ian I considered this but since this is within the for loop -- for f in selection: -- wouldn't this be enough? or is this different because it's just attributes and we would need to run a .geometry() loop for both? Basically all it's supposed to do for each road segment is to check which locality (polygon) it's in and fill in the locality column with this value.

Comment: yes you're right it is nested already! Just had a look at the answer you've linked to and the format of the if statement is slightly different to yours  'a.geometry.intersects(b.geometry())' have you tried removing the brackets from after f.geometry?

Comment: Thanks - I now get -- AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'within'-- I also tried it with 'intersects' instead.

Comment: @GeorgeC - Sorry, the expression should be in string: `e = QgsExpression( "geomwithin('Locality_layer','Locality_N') ")`

Comment: @Joseph -thanks now there are no failures but the values aren't updated in the table.

Comment: @GeorgeC - Does it work if you use the expression `geomwithin('Locality_layer','Locality_N')` in the field calculator?

Comment: Yes but I had to add the layer to the canvas -it wasn't enough to just call it and it also needed to be the name used in QgsVectorLayer(...)  Happy to accept an answer that you post if you want to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After ensuring you loaded your vector layer, you could use the following:

```
##Update LocalityName
e = QgsExpression( "geomwithin('Locality','Locality_N') ")
f[fieldName] = e.evaluate()
layer.updateFeature(f)
```