# Need to change projection and data to match 2nd shapefile

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I have two files I am using, one is census tract data with prj:

```
GEOGCS["GCS_North_American_1983",
    DATUM["D_North_American_1983",
         SPHEROID["GRS_1980",6378137.0,298.257222101]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],
    UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]]
```

The other is a grid file from a model with prj:

```
PROJCS["airpact",
    GEOGCS["GCS_Sphere_EMEP",
       DATUM["D_Sphere_EMEP",
         SPHEROID["Sphere_EMEP",6370000.0,0.0]],
       PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],
       UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    PROJECTION["Lambert_Conformal_Conic"],
    PARAMETER["False_Easting",0.0],
    PARAMETER["False_Northing",0.0],
    PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",-121.0],
    PARAMETER["Standard_Parallel_1",30.0],
    PARAMETER["Standard_Parallel_2",60.0],
    PARAMETER["Scale_Factor",1.0],
    PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",49.0],
    UNIT["Meter",1.0]]
```

**Data file**
In layer spatial reference system units

```
xMin,yMin -124.849,41.988 : xMax,yMax -111.043,49.0025
```

Layer Spatial Reference System

```
+proj=longlat +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +no_defs
```

**Grid file**
In layer spatial reference system units

```
xMin,yMin -342000.00,-942000.00 : xMax,yMax 798000.00,90000
```

Layer Spatial Reference System

```
+proj=lcc +lat_1=30 +lat_2=60 +lat_0=49 +lon_0=-121 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6370000 +b=6370000 +units=m +no_defs
```

My problem is obvious, these are nowhere near the same and when I load into qgis the grid is far larger than the census tract data. I need to define them both on the same projection as the grid without ruining the census data but I am not sure how to do this. I have read several similar questions but am still lost.

I am aware that the census data is referencing lat/lon in degrees and the grid is in projected coordinates in meters, but need to somehow convert the census data to match the grid.

Comment: The easiest way for showing data together would be to activate the on-the-fly reprojecting in QGIS.

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/73686/how-can-i-change-the-projection-of-shapefile-in-qgis The answers to this question may help you.