# Get DD Lat and Lon from CRS EPSG:3111 - GDA94

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, latitude-longitude

I have a shapefile in **CRS EPSG:3111 - GDA94**  that I am trying to generate Lat and Lon, however when I use the field calculator and try to populate the lat lon I am getting values that I can't use as per the screenshot below - 
[image]

I am expecting something in this format - [image]

I have projected it in EPSG:4326 but didnt help

[image]

Comment: I don't know the solution in QGIS, but you're getting the Vicgrid northing coordinate. You may need to reproject the layer to GDA94: EPSG:4283.

Comment: @mkennedy have tried that but with no results. Have Set the CRS to 4326 and 4283 but the same Lat Lon is displayed

Comment: Please see [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/73686/changing-projection-of-shapefile-in-qgis).

Comment: @mkennedy thanks, the layer is converted to CRS EPSG:4283 but when I try to generate the Lat using field calculator and use `x_at(1)` I get 2498498.3060000017

Comment: EPSG:3111 is a Lamberts' projection using the GDA94 datum, it's units are metres. GDA94/Geographic is, as stated, EPSG:4283. Changing to WGS84/Geographic (EPSG:4326) isn't helping, it's close but not the same. Please describe how you are projecting to a geographic coordinate system, I suspect you're simply overwriting the correct CRS with an incorrect one which won't change the numbers *at all*. Try right clicking on the layer in VicGrid 3111 and select *save as* then in the dialog *implicitly specify* EPSG:4283 and you should get Lat/Lon coordinates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can reproject the shapes while computing the coordinate. Instead of using `x_at(1)`, you can use

```
 x( point_n( transform( $geometry,'EPSG:3311','EPSG:4283'),1))
```

`x(geom)` -> get the X coordinate
`point_n(geom, 1)` -> get the 1st vertice
`transform (geom, sourceCRS, destCRS)` -> reproject

Answer (score 1):

The steps JGH outlined will solve the issue if you are working from clean data. However, it seems you have incorrectly changed the CRS of your layer. **Changing the CRS in the layer properties is not the same as re-projecting the layer.**

Assuming that you changed the CRS in the layer properties, you have to fix that mistake before you can use the layer for anything. Change the CRS (in layer properties) back to the CRS it was before you changed it the first time.