# Large offset between two identical vector layers

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, dxf, reprojection-mathematics, offset

I want to have a dxf layer to overlay another layer. The dxf layer is already saved to a shapefile with the needed crs. The layer has a large offset and nothing happens when I set the crs to the needed RD NEW/ EPSG 28992, it has a large offset. The feature is far away from the place it should be and it is rotated. I think this is due to the fact that there was no geometry assigned when it was drawn as a DWG/DXF.

How can I rotate the shapefile layer and move it to the right place?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/73686/changing-projection-of-shapefile-in-qgis

Comment: I have gone through these steps, however the layer does not move.

Comment: can you clarify what you are doing to "set the CRS of the layer"

Comment: Right-click on layer that needs to be moved --> 'Set layer crs' --> Select 'Amersfoort / RD New' --> press 'ok'

Comment: that is not the correct way to do it unless it is already in that projection, which it seems like it is not