# Rescaling the coordinates of shapefile

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, shapefile, coordinates

I have a few shapefiles that I am analyzing in QGIS. They are in the WGS 84 coordinate reference system, which is what I want, however, the coordinates are in the seven digit range (they are all around 3829665, 5878362). How can I scale the coordinates all down by 10^5? e.g. I want them all around 38.29665, 58.78362

Comment: are you sure those coordinates are in WGS84? It's not a matter or rounding the numbers to get what you want... My guess are those are in some other projected coordinate system and need to be projected into WGS84...

Comment: I think the issue is that WGS84 UTM and WGS84 Geographic are both referred to as WGS84. Please post the contents of the .prj file that should be associated with your shapefiles - they should be all text. If the projection is well defined you should be able to right click to save as then specify the output coordinate system as WGS84 Geographic (EPSG:4326) to convert the coordinates, read the answer to https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/73686/changing-projection-of-shapefile-in-qgis and take the 3rd option.