# QGIS not properly projecting coordinates on new shapefile

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I am using QGIS Desktop Version 3.34.1

Preface: I am fairly new to QGIS but I have tried to look up the answer before. Example: [Changing projection of shapefile in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/73686/changing-projection-of-shapefile-in-qgis) which does not seem to work.

Problem:
A State's mapping system asks that you upload all data using a specific coordinate reference system (CRS). I have created a shapefile with that specific CRS in QGIS. However, when I upload that data into the State's mapping system it relocates my data to Africa. (Despite saying that the CRS is correct).

Resolutions Tried:
I tried downloading Shapefile data with the proper CRS from the State's website and launching in QGIS. Without editing the file, I hit "Export As" -Esri Shapefile -Proper CRS.
This then moves the previously correct data with the same CRS as my new shapefile to Africa despite it having the proper coordinate system.

Where am I going wrong?

State Mapping System: [GranitView](https://granitview.unh.edu/html5viewer/index.html?viewer=granit_view)

Shapefile Layer: [State Data Layer I uploaded to QGIS and hit "Export As" with](https://new-hampshire-geodata-portal-1-nhgranit.hub.arcgis.com/datasets/NHGRANIT::new-hampshire-conservation-public-lands/about)

This may be a lot of data for some users. It might be faster to go to the State Mapping System make your own test shapefile -this will automatically give your shapefile the EPSG:3437 - NAD83 / New Hampshire (ftUS) which the State asks for.

Coordinate Reference System State Website asks for and uses:  [Comparison of State vs My Shapefile Data](https://ibb.co/DGFymRB)

[image]

I have included extent and the Layer Properties information.

@John directed me to  the   CRS box.  They  are correct that my default for Project and Layers differed from the  projection I wanted and was  left on  WGS 84. I will definitely keep that in mind in the future.  After reprojecting the  layer via Vector-> Data  Management- > I am still   in  Africa.

If I start a  brand   new  project with correct CRS Box from above and make  a   new  layer  I  am still  in  Africa.

[image: Still Swimming in Africa]In  Africa

Step 1. Start New QGIS Project. Settings->Options->CRS Handling. Make sure that the CRS is EPSG:3437-NAD83/New Hampshire (ftUS)[image]Close the project and start a new one just to ensure that the changes took place. CRS of the project reads. EPSG:3437-NAD83/New Hampshire (ftUS).

Step 2. Take State Data and drop it into my Project. State Data has a projected CRS as EPSG:3437-NAD83/New Hampshire (ftUS). See above picture.

Step 3. Hit "New Shapefile Layer"[image]
and draw an example shapefile layer. Hit Save layer.

Step 4. Compare newly created Shapefile layer CRS with the imported CRS of the State Data file. CRS are the same.
My New Shapefile in QGIS displays nicely and in the correct location as I desire.
Example Shapefile[image]

Step 5. Launch Granit. Go to "Upload Data"
Step 6. Upload newly created Shapefile with matching CRS as Conservation Layer.
Step 7. Stare at new Shapefile in Africa.

What I did with NH State Data to get it to Africa:

Load State Data into QGIS see above screenshot. Right Click file layer on left hand screen. -> Export->Save Feature As->ESRI Shapefile with CRS NAD 83.
Step 2. Go to Granit. Upload newly exported Data Set into Granit->Moves to Africa.

I believe @Vince is correct that there is something wrong with the extents of the project when they said:

> They are very different, but the projection is listed as being the
> same. That can't be right. This may turn out to be a duplicate of our
> most frequent duplicate Question.

While the Conservation Layer says NAD 83 it might actually be WGS 84 as when I make a shapefile with the WGS 84 CRS instead of the NAD 83 CRS it places it properly in the States Webmap.

This is my guess unless you see that I have missed something in the process.

I have asked the Webmap to clarify.

Comment: Please [Edit] the Question to include the exact `.prj` file contents and the extent of the file (minx/miny/maxx/maxy)

Comment: The Question needs to be standalone, not dependent on links. If I need to follow a link to know what your extent is, I'm going to vote to close the question as *lacking details*.

Comment: What are your settings in the Settings - Options - CRS Handling dialog box?  What CRS is your project in looking at Project- Properties - CRS?   A common problem is for a user to change a layer's CRS simply by changing its projection definition instead of actually reprojecting it.  Thus right clicking on a layer and changing its layer CRS is telling QGIS it has a projection defined but it is not reprojecting it.  You only change a definition when the current one is wrong or undefined.  To change a correctly defined layer to a new CRS, reproject it.

Comment: Look at your extents. They are very different, but the projection is listed as being the same. That can't be right. This may turn out to be a duplicate of our most frequent duplicate Question. You need to Reproject data to change coordinate systems for existing data. Do not ever Define a projection on an existing file.

Comment: "I have created a shapefile..." What exactly did you do? "Without editing the file, I hit "Export As" -Esri Shapefile -Proper CRS." What exactly did you do? Screen shots please.

Comment: OK, I found the "Upload Data" button on the GranitView site. I exported and uploaded one of the polygons, but I'm unable to replicate your problem. More screen shots please of what you're seeing.

Comment: "What did I do with NH State Data to get it to Africa?"
Gut feeling tells me somewhere in between steps 4 and 6 you are redefining your EPSG:3437 shapefile to EPSG:3857.